# Xamarin - Can't create and run a blank cross platform application

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

I am new to Xamarin. I have just installed Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin 
and now I am trying to build a new blank cross platform app.

When I build it, it builds successfully. However, when I try to run it in the emulator, it launches but I can't see any output on the screen. It also takes a long time to launch.

Has anyone faced this issue too?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx) or
[Xamarin Android Player](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/http://).
when you create a new project, try updating Xamarin.Forms and other library in NuGet.

Comment: by default vs 2015 with xamarin use visual studio emulator for android i think

Comment: FYI: `Xamarin Android Player` is deprecated and not longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

1) Verify in the portable and android project right click in Manage Nuget Package if you have installed the Xamarin.Form [image: Solution Explorer]

2) Control Panel -> Program and Features -> Visual Studio 2015 doble click and press the button Modify. verify that you updated the installation of Visual Studio.

3) Open the visual studio. Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Others. press the link (Check Now) for updates of the xamarin.

4)Open the SDK Manager and verify that you have installed the API 19 [image: SDK Manager]

5) and finally try to clean the solution and rebuild the project. And run. If this doesn't work.

6) watch the error in the output of the visual studio, if exist any error, or you need some library you watch in this section.